# Doubt about high voltage measurement from amp chassis to earth ground

Tags: amplifier, grounding, vacuum-tube

I built a tube amp (Fender 5f1 replica) and it works perfectly with a 3 prong power cord plugged into a properly earth grounded outlet. Any voltage on chassis and practically no "hum".
I did an experiment, plugging the amp in an outlet that is not grounded (only hot and neutral) and if I take my multimeter, one lead to the chassis and another directly to the earth ground of an outlet that is properly grounded and I can measure something about 300V AC.
My question is if this is "normal", because the center tap of HV winding of the power transformer is connected to the chassis or is this due to capacitive coupling (induced voltage of the PT)?

I'm attaching an image of the actual amplifier layout I built.
[image]

Below is also the transformer schematic:

[image]

At my home, I only play the guitar with the amp in the properly grounded outlet so I have no risk/trouble. But what if I go to another house that has no grounded outlets and want to play some guitar there? (this is my actual concern).
Thanks!

After all the help and some search, I got to the conclusion that the measured voltage was just "stray voltage" or "ghost voltage".
As my multimeter does not have the Low impedance option, I did a test putting a 3k resistor in parallel with the meter leads and now the measurement is around just 0.8V AC as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to plug 3 prong power cord into outlet without ground?

Comment: Actually all the outlets are of the 3 prong type but the earth connection is not connected to anything. Although I have a single outlet that is actually made and grounded by myself with a ground rod I put in the backyard. I did this because the house is rented and I can't modify all the electrical wiring.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a proper schematic. A properly drawn schematic could tell you where the 300VAC originate. I don't see how the transformator is wired here. Note that a multimeter will lie to you unless it has a low-z measurment capability.

Comment: Ouch... that is what I call "living dangerously" :) Sorry I cannot help you, because that picture does not tell me what is going on inside a transformer.

Comment: Hahah, no problem, I just added the transformer schematic. About the windings, the primary is for 127V, and secondary I'm telling about is the middle one, that provides 650V divided by the center tap at 325V. Thanks!

Comment: About the multimeter, mine has no that low-z measurement feature.

Comment: Nice work!. If you have no connection to chassis beside the center prong, then it is likely some leakage (capacitive / resistive / inductive). I know you can say that, too.:). If you cannot find the source, then try to couple the chassis to  neutral, so you can less suffer from the shock. Meantime, did you wire up some points to the chassis to reduce the hum? I found better way to kill the hum is filtering the line. I used bridge diodes and caps for filament (6.3V), and it really quieted the hum, may be too much.

Comment: Thanks @jay, about the "hum" it is not so much when using the 3 prong on a correctly grounded outlet. I like the diodes and caps for the 6.3V filament idea to diminish the "hum", thanks.

Comment: If the earth ground on chassis prevents the hum, then that means; the line frequency is coupled to chassis -> fed back to high impedance points. Meantime, good side is that you know it is coupled to chassis. One way would be make the chassis ground to your circuit ground, as like olden days. Before that, you may want to know the amount of the leakage. To do that, connect a 1Meg ohm from chassis to the earth ground and measure the voltage. If the voltage is any significant, then you need to find the leakage and fix it before pop to smoke.

Comment: Thanks! I will tray that.

Comment: As my meter does not have the Low impedance option, I put a 3k resistor in parallel with the meter leads, obtaining an AC measurement of only 0.8V and this way I came to the conclusion that the previously measured high voltage on the chassis (300V AC) was just a "stray" / "ghost" voltage caused by capacitive coupling. Thanks all!

Comment: Is your grounding rod just a signal ground? Or is it bonded to the neutral wiring in your building?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, it is independent, not bonded to the neutral.